# cancel axios request if it exceeds timeout and retry if the previous requests were timed out in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have tried different ways to find the answer.
If I use cancelToken library in axios(npm package). Once the request is cancelled, we can't retry the request. The request won't go to the next line(even after timeout) until it receives a response from the axios request.

I need an answer to cancel a request after timeout and should also retry the request incase of timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios has an option "timeout", after that threshold it will cancel the request. So you can write something like this:

```
const TIMEOUT = 3000; // millisecods
let succeededResponse = null;

while(!succeededResponse) {
    try {
        succeededResponse = await axios.get("https://somewhere.any", { timeout: TIMEOUT });
    } catch(e) {
        // as axios will throw an error in case of timeout, you'll need this try-catch block
    }
}
// axios will request until it gets the response in the specified threshold
// here succeededResponse will have a value
```